# Android frame recorder with accessing frame for analyst

Tags: java, android

I've make an app to record the device screen but not for save to video, my purpose is to access the video frame while recoding to do some AI task.
I've try with MediaProjection and ImageReader. I've success receive the frame but there are problem.

I've run and test on my 2 device: OPPO F11 and Redmi Note 11S

- On OPPO F11, if using ImageFormat is JPEG, i will receive graphic buffer allowcate error. It working for ImageFormat RGB_565 or YUV_420_888
- On Redmi, i only can use the ImageFormat JPEG because there will be error indicate that output producer output image with that type, so i can't use other ImageFormat type.

Anyone have problem like this and Are there any other method to making the app logic like i want.

This is my current code:

```java
package com.example.faceextract;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private int screenDensity;
    private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection mediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;
    private static final int AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private int width = 720, height = 1280;

    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get references to UI elements
        startBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_recording);
        stopBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_recording);

        // Get screen density
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
        // Initialize media projection manager
        mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestRecordingPermissionsAndStart();
            }
        });

        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopRecording();
            }
        });

        // start capture handling thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void requestRecordingPermissionsAndStart() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("DEBUGGGGGG", "vào");
            startRecording();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
        try {

            // Request permission to capture the screen
            // Inside MainActivity's startRecording method
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MediaProjectionService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            } else {
                startService(serviceIntent);
            }
            startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        startBtn.setEnabled(true);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mediaProjection.stop();
        mediaProjection = null;

        virtualDisplay.release();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == AUDIO_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Audio permission granted, you can start recording
                startRecording();
            } else {
                // Audio permission denied, handle accordingly
                Toast.makeText(this, "Audio permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            startBtn.setEnabled(true);
            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Screen Cast Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
        virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay(mImageReader.getSurface());

        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Log.i("OK","FORMAT" +  reader.getImageFormat());
                Image image = null;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireNextImage();

                    if(image != null) {
//                        Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();

                    }

                    image.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, mHandler);
    }

    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay(Surface surface) {
        final int flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
        return mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                width,height, screenDensity,
                flags,
                surface, new VirtualDisplayCallback(), mHandler);
    }

    private class VirtualDisplayCallback extends VirtualDisplay.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            super.onPaused();
            Log.e("VIRTUAL", "VirtualDisplayCallback: onPaused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResumed() {
            super.onResumed();
            Log.e("VIRTUAL", "VirtualDisplayCallback: onResumed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            Log.e("VIRTUAL", "VirtualDisplayCallback: onStopped");
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for your time reading and helping